# SSH into Mac server and port forward - Possible to tunnel the connection?

Tags: ssh

I set up a server at home, and I never got around to anything else than remote SSH access (basically port forward port 22).

Now I'm outside of home, and I realised how much I actually need to use the server physically, which is why I want to port forward externally (through SSH), so I can set up a remote connection (because some programs only have GUI).

Assuming I only have an SSH connection open, how would I go to http://192.168.1.1 and port forward other ports? Basically set up my own Macbook to handle the connection through SSH, so I can use my Macbook like I was at home.

Comment: I used to work like that. It was not pratical. I ended up setting up the modem/router of the provider in bridge modem and setup my own Linux box with strongswan giving me a VPN to the outside.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I figured it out.

```
ssh -D 8080 -C -N USERNAME@home.ip
```

And then set up the Macbook to use a SOCKS proxy on port 8080.